# Word javascript add-in auto open doesn't work

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I have developed a word add-in and promoted to add-in store. I have implemented auto open task pane as described in add-in document(https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) but my add-in pane is not loading when I open the document, I have to every time click the Icon that was placed when I installed(added) the add-in from store.

IS there any other factors controlling auto open functionality? Please help me.

Comment: Consider adding more detail about what you've tried. Specifically, what does the WebExtension part of the OpenXML look like, what build of Word are you trying this in?

Comment: Also, show some parts of the manifest, like schema version, that is related to the project. Does it open when you run locally or on Office Online (uploading the manifest)?

Comment: I'm using Word 2016 - 16.0.8201-2200 build and my document webextension openxml looks like                                                             
<we:webextension id="{AE9B1970-3961-4B03-B3C7-3C80719184FB}" xmlns:we="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/webextensions/webextension/2010/11">
<we:reference id="wa104381318" storeType="OMEX" store="en-US" version="1.0.0.0"/>
<we:alternateReferences/>
<we:properties>
<we:property value="true" name="Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument"/>
</we:properties>
</we:webextension>     I removed some tag from xml to fit into the comment limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID after webextension needs to match the ID that's in the manifest submitted to the Office Store. When using the snippet above this fails because the store id - wa104381318, does not match {AE9B1970... which you have above.

Changing it to {B95BF4FD-FCD8-4064-BF56-7B6EA9938F9} should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Sean. I tried the change you suggested but still it is not working. Every time I add my add-in to word it put a different Id but I change that to {B95BF4FD-FCD8-4064-BF56-7B6EA9938F9} did not work. Is there any other part I'm missing?

Comment: The correct GUID in manifest is {B95BF4FD-FCD8-4064-BF56-7B6EA9938F9C} I tried this too doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in the guid in my above comment.  I do have this properly working for me with your addin in both Word Win32 and Word Online.  A few things to test: Try downloading this sample word file for your add-in - https://1drv.ms/w/s!Atf-NP-lo39-oLk-_3lVvnHRnCIQbQ.  If that works then its a problem in your mark-up. If not its a problem in the host application.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Document you attached is not working for me. If it is working for you pointing our host should work for me too right? Is there any special needs in host application to accommodate auto open changes? please advise me.

Comment: Sean, Can you try the add-in in desktop office 2016. We tried in office 2016  It is not working for us but it is working on office 2013.

Comment: It works fine in my build of Office 2016.  I'm going to follow up with the team for more debugging tips. Can you run fiddler while opening the document?  If so, you should see a call to store.office.com with the payload of: wa104381318.  If you see that call, what's in the response?

Comment: In 2013 I can see the call to store.office.com with payload wa104381318 when open the document (also add-in opens automatically) but in 2016 I don't see the call.

Comment: In word 2016 I can see this call when I click on the add-in button in the menu bar ( I created CustomTab in the add-in command so I have a menu tab on my word menu if I click that menu I can see the call but not on open a document with add-in)

Comment: Office 2013 has a form of AutoOpen without Add-in Commands.  It'll auto-open until the user closes it at which point it will no longer auto-open. Office 2016 introduced add-in commands but disabled the original auto open task pane feature.  Later in Office 2016, the new AutoOpen with add-in commands was introduced.  Your build of Office might be in the in-between state.  Can you provide the text on the line below 1711 (Build ...)? It might say something like Deferred Channel or Semi Annual.  If that's the case, the functionality is stilling out to customers like yourself.

Comment: Thank you Sean, Yes my Office 2016 version is 1705 and Deferred Channel. I tried to update Office but couldn't find the correct version. Can you please provide the url to latest update? Once again thank you for you time.

Comment: Deferred Channel (also called SemiAnnual) is typically used by Enterprises who want to slow the pace of updates.  Ordinarily, you'd need to work with your admin for them to make it available. If you have the option, you may switch your channel to the Current (Monthly) Channel by following these instructions - these instructions - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3185078/how-to-switch-from-deferred-channel-to-current-channel-for-the-office

Comment: I also apologize for all the confusion. We had a bug in our documentation indicating that it was widely available on the wrong build number.